# Java - creating threads in a EventListener

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, runtime

I got this code:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        OctopusWSClient.sendPoolSensorReading(poolSensorReading, OctopusClientStart.currentMacAddress);
                    }
                });
                thread.setName("Thread - WS");
                thread.start();
```

Is inside a Event Listener that is executing approximately every 30 seconds (When an event occurs), so is creating a new Thread every 30 seconds that usually last 20 seconds to complete, now, my question is... Its OK to call Threads this way?, if not, how???... and also, I'm watching Threads ID and names with this code:

```
Set<Thread> threadSet = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
                for(Thread t : threadSet){
                    System.out.println(" Thread #"+t.getId()+" Name: "+t.getName());
                }
```

and it prints the ID and name for the current threads, I see always the same number of Threads, but the ID is always incrementing by 1 (Thread - WS).

Is this a bad signal? It will fill JVM Memory in some time?

thanks

Comment: sendPoolSensorReading is a static method, doesn't implements Runnable

Comment: You could use an [executor service](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html) instead

Comment: This is what thread pools are designed for. They eliminate the overhead of perpetually constructing and destroying threads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would probably find it better to notify a single thread to resume, rather than create multiple ones. If it takes 20 seconds to complete, at the end lock it and make it wait till it gets the command to restart the loop from the event listener.

Comment: Add in a queue to allow for back fill and nice idea

Comment: That actually would work better, in case there is a time offset if it took to long at any point.

Comment: I don't understand, could you help me please with a little example, thanks

Comment: Something quick I whipped up: [link](http://pastebin.com/gQNY58Xz). I used a `Scanner` there, to check for the 'action' to continue. You should be able to work it out with that.