# Thread, Arraylist impact on Memory - Java

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, out-of-memory

My input data is 50,000 (or more) email messages in one list and there is huge duplication in that dur to multiple recipients in to,cc and bcc. Hence I need to extract unique message from this list.

I have to compare certain properties (From, To list and contain(String only)) of Message to identify if there are same or not.

Right now I am dividing this 50,000 messages in to 50 small 1000 message list and running each small list's duplication in it's thread.

All thread add it's output to one list and finally I check for duplication in that thread.
While I do that my JVM reach to 1.25 GB memory.

Hence if I try and push anything more then 50,000 Messages I get an Out Of Memory Error.

I have method called `removeDeduplicate(array of messages, blank list)`, which take array of messages and empty list as input and return unique message in that blank list.
This is my code:

```
public Message[] processForDeduplication(Message[] msgs) throws MessagingException, IOException, InterruptedException {
    final List<Message> output = new ArrayList<Message>();

    if(msgs.length < MAX_MSG){
        output.addAll(removeDeduplication(msgs, new ArrayList<Message>()));
    } else {
        List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
        int index = 0, lastIndex = MAX_MSG;

        while(index < msgs.length){
            if(lastIndex >= msgs.length) {
                lastIndex = msgs.length;
            }
            final Message[] temp = Arrays.copyOfRange(msgs, index, lastIndex);
            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        output.addAll(removeDeduplication(temp, new ArrayList<Message>()));
                    } catch (MessagingException ex) {
                        logger.error(EmailComparator.class.getName() +  ex);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        logger.error(EmailComparator.class.getName() +  ex);
                    }
                }
             });
             t.start();
             threads.add(t);
            index = lastIndex;
            lastIndex = lastIndex + MAX_MSG;
        }
        for(Thread t: threads){
            while(t.isAlive()){
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
        }
        threads = null;
    }
    List<Message> results = removeDeduplication(convertToArray(output), new ArrayList<Message>());
    return convertToArray(results);
}
```

I am trying to fine tune my code for Memory enhancement and performance too.
Right now it takes about 12-15 seconds to finish 50,000 records I would like that to be 5-6 seconds.

Comment: You create a new thread every loop. Create one thread and add instances to a queue to be processed by it.

Comment: I resolved a very similar issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14737541/java-creating-threads-in-a-eventlistener/14737583#14737583

Comment: @Legend But that mean one thread doing all work, I loose multiprocessing and hence it will take long time very long time.

Comment: Wow, you've way over-engineered this. 50k items is a tiny list, just add them to a treeset with a proper comparator and your done.

Comment: Then created a defined amount of threads, possibly 4-5. If you overload the amount of threads it will have a negative effect.

Comment: Can't you just use some java.util.Set (maybe synchronized Set) in place where you are collecting messages? So that latest duplication removing won't be necessary?

Comment: @ŁukaszRzeszotarski They are emails. If Email sent to 10 ppl Email server generates 10 emails as it think it is sending them to 10 diff ppls so I get 10 diff object but with different properties.

Comment: @Perception I'need to have a look and try treeset. I'll let you know how it went.. cheers

Comment: @Perception When I said duplication, I mean they are different objects with same properties hence I have to compare their properties to make sure they are same. TreeSet doesn't work on that principle

Comment: @bhavin Perceptions' solution says to use a comparator.  A comparator lets you take two objects and inspect them for equality or sorting purposes.  You could also just implement .equals() (and .hashCode()) on your Message object and shove everything into a HashSet to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what your `Message` is so I assumed it was a `javax.mail.Message`. I created a wrapper object that checks for equality of messages as you specified. This object caches the `from` and the `to` arrays as `Set`s - this allows for faster equals comparison as `Set`s have an O(1) contains method.
The wrapper also caches the `hashCode` so that it doesn't have to be recomputed by the `Set`.

```
public static class MessageWrapper {

    private final Message message;
    private final Set<Address> from;
    private final Set<Address> to;
    private final Object content;
    private final int hashCode;

    public MessageWrapper(Message message) throws MessagingException, IOException {
        this.message = message;
        this.from = new HashSet<Address>(Arrays.asList(message.getFrom()));
        this.to = new HashSet<Address>(Arrays.asList(message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO)));
        this.content = message.getContent();
        this.hashCode = calcHashCode();
    }

    public Message getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    private int calcHashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 37 * hash + (this.from != null ? this.from.hashCode() : 0);
        hash = 37 * hash + (this.to != null ? this.to.hashCode() : 0);
        hash = 37 * hash + (this.content != null ? this.content.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return hashCode;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final MessageWrapper other = (MessageWrapper) obj;
        if (this.from != other.from && (this.from == null || !this.from.equals(other.from))) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.to != other.to && (this.to == null || !this.to.equals(other.to))) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.content != other.content && (this.content == null || !this.content.equals(other.content))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

The most expensive thing to store is really the `content` - you may want to consider only storing `content.hashCode` and then comparing that; this would allow clashes however.

Now all you need to do is put all the `Message`s into `MessageWrapper`s and put that into a `HashSet` - this will automatically drop items that are `equals()`

```
public Message[] processForDeduplication(final Message[] messages) throws MessagingException, IOException {
    final Set<MessageWrapper> messageWrappers = new HashSet<MessageWrapper>(messages.length, 1.0f);
    for (final Message m : messages) {
        messageWrappers.add(new MessageWrapper(m));
    }
    final List<Message> ms = new ArrayList<Message>(messages.length);
    for (final MessageWrapper wrapper : messageWrappers) {
        ms.add(wrapper.getMessage());
    }
    return ms.toArray(new Message[messages.length]);
}
```

It's a little messy as you have to convert the thing back into a `Message[]` at the end.

Obviously if your `Message` isn't a `javax.mail.Message` the implementation may be different. You may even be able to implement `equals` and `hashCode` directly on the class in question.

Comment: I tried your code bmorris591. And as I expected the HASH doesn't work properly. It generated different HASH foe each same object and hence it never going to work. But Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Well, As I said - you need to modify that to your needs - work out **exactly** what needs to be equal and write the methods appropriately. Create  a simple test case with 2-3 messages and tailor the method appropriately.